# Jenkins pipeline to import existing AWS resources into Terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for adding a step into Jenkins pipeline(Declarative pipeline) to import existing AWS resources into Terraform code. Could someone please help me on this. I want to use this pipeline for any rebuild infrastructure

Comment: Were you able to find answers? I'm looking to do the same thing